# Add non-explicit types to .net web api client

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a webapi myproj.csproj that is a .net core 3.0 web api. it compiles to a myproj client that contains all the necessary api endpoints and all types *explicitly* associated with those endpoints.

I have an endpoint that is like the following:

```
public async Task<string> GetReportDataAsync(Guid reportType, long id)
```

where I pass in a guid of the report type and another id, it does a calculation and returns a json string. I would like to make the type used to serialize to json on the server side available in my client so I can easily deserialize the string:

```
string reportOutput = await ApiClient.GetReportDataAsync(<reportTypeGuid>, <id>);
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyReportType>(reportOutput);
```

without having to create a new API endpoint for every report type I add. Is there a way to force the web api to compile the types I ask it to for easy client consumption?

I could create a new api endpoint for every single report type, but I would rather not do that if I have 10+ report types. The existing endpoint already does what I need it to, I just want to deserialize the type.

I realize it's designed this way to have only what the client would need, just wondering if anyone has run into this.

Report Type (there are more properties than this but they are all of type long):

```
namespace Reports.ReportTypes
{
    public class MyReportType : ReportTypeBase
    {
        public long JobRunId { get; set; }
        public long Size { get; set; }
        public long Count { get; set; }
        //...
        public long SomeOtherCount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect at the client? If the client had the name of the type you are transmitting, could it reconstruct the type on the fly (i.e., does the client have access to enough information to know what `MyReportType` means)? If so, you could do your client side work using reflection. If not you could reply with _JSON Schema_ that describes the schema of the response messages.

Comment: Could you please share the details of `MyReportType` with us?

Comment: @Flydog57 the client could certainly use reflection, I just wanted to avoid this and let the client deserialize without having to do any additional work. I'm guessing the answer to this is "no you can't add types to a client that aren't explicitly called out in the API contracts", but thought maybe there was a way.

Comment: You can deserialize at the client without knowing the type (into a `dynamic` of some type).  But, then you'll need to know what to go looking for client-side.  One way to do this is to create an Interface (consisting of property declarations) and let both sides know about it (via some back-channel - source, a zip file of an assembly, whatever)